# UseFetch calling request immediately after changing parameters (Nuxt 3)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="beer in beersResponse">{{ beer.name }}</div>
    <button @click="handleNextPage">Go to next page</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const currentPage = ref(1);

const beerRequestParameters = computed(() => {
  return {
    per_page: 2,
    page: currentPage.value,
  };
});

const { data: beersResponse } = await useFetch(
  "https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers",
  {
    params: beerRequestParameters,
  }
);

function handleNextPage() {
  currentPage.value += 1;
}
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/usefetch-bug-forked-yyrjsy?file=%2Fapp.vue%3A13%2C17&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A3%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A3%7D%5D

UseFetch refreshing and calling request immediately after changing params.
What I want to do is to update params for that request and then call it later via refresh/execure function, but instead this request is called immediately after changing parameters.

It works as intended, page is changed after clicking the button, but i feel like it is not really readable, i would prefer to explicitly call function to fetch data with new parameters.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you mean you want to do something like [this example](https://vueuse.org/core/useFetch/#prevent-request-from-firing-immediately) from the official documentation?

Comment: That is the behavior of useFetch. It generates a key based on the fetch options to cache API responses, which means when the fetch options change, then a re-fetch is automatically triggered. Can you provide more context on what exactly you're trying to achieve? What is not readable? Why exactly do you want to fetch later? Based on the code that you provided, the "Go to next page" button does exactly what is intended to, which is to re-fetch when clicked.